# CRUD operation on Generic Repository in C# gives error in other class

Tags: c#, crud

I'm implementing CRUD operation in Generic repository using C#
here is my base class code.

```
public class Base<TObject> where TObject : EntityObject   
{
    protected HMSEntities _context;
```

and so on

Class inherit from base class has the code

```
public class AmountDLL: Base<Tbl_Amount>
{     

    public override Tbl_Amount Add(Tbl_Amount t)
    {
        return base.Add(t);

    }
```

but it gives me error:

> **"The type 'DataLogic.Tbl_Amount' cannot be used as type parameter 'TObject' in the generic type or method 'Base'. There is no
>   implicit reference conversion from 'DataLogic.Tbl_Amount' to
>   'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityObject'"**

Please suggest me solution 
Thanks in advance

Comment: this link maybe help you : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423736/convert-library-from-objectcontext-to-dbcontext

Comment: its too complicated. i want simple one.

Comment: Edit the question and show the class EntityObject?

Comment: Can you show us the definition of `Tbl_Amount`?